# CORS requests blocked in chrome extension

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm new to the chrome extension develop. I've tried to get a JSON file from a simple API sevice but without success, the `$.getJSON` method will be blocked because it's a CORS request and it's not allowed. I've read some questions here on SO, but I can't figure out how to proceed to make an ajax request to the API service, can anyone show mw an example? I only have the popup.html file and popup.js that will contain my logics and layout, no background,js file is present in my extension folder, is this needed?

this is the error i get:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at '...' (redirected from '...') from origin 'chrome-extension://mhgnneiaahgopaabnljbmglekgbaanio' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

### NB: I've already added the permissions to the api url

### Manifest

```
{
  "name": "ChMStats",
  "short_name": "CBMS",
  "version": "1.0",
  "author": "P",
  "description": "!",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "https://siteurl.com/api/*"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

### popup.js

```
(function($){
  $(document).ready(function(){
    console.log('Extension Started!');
    const url = 'https://siteurl.com/api/?user=username&token=token';
    $('#getStats').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.spinner-grow').css({'display':'block'});
      $.getJSON(url, function(response){
        $('.spinner-grow').css({'display':'none'});
          var html = '<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Username '+response.username+'</li>';
          html += '<li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">Token Balance <span="badge badge-danger badge-pill">'+response.token_balance+'</span></li>';
          $('.response').append(html);
      });
    });
  });
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: You need to add the matching URL pattern in your manifest.json's permissions as explained [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr). Don't forget to click the reload icon on chrome://extensions card for your extension. And if this won't help you'll need to edit your question and add [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Comment: I've added the url but it will not work

Comment: There's nothing rilevent to show, just a `$.getJSON()` method and the manifest, I will update the question.

Comment: I've posted here a modified version, in my code I have only the host. The problem isn't with the API but with the CORS requests that are blocked since chrome 73. It's not clear form me how to fix this.

Comment: After some debug i've solved the issue. the api was redirecting the request to a specific subdomain for my country. Now I need to pack my extension to distribute it, any help? I don't need the chrome store

Comment: This is a good find worthy of an answer. Please add one.